# MVVM TreeView on Database

Tags: mvvm

(please excuse my bad english)

i have a hierachical database where every row references another row with a FK
it allows me to use the navigation property from the entity framework to create a treeview.

like so.
[the tutorial for hierachical database to treeview(the easy way)](http://devjitsu.com/blog/2010/04/22/hierarchical-data-trees-with-a-database/)

In xaml it looks like.

```
<sdk:TreeView Name="treeView1" >
                <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders1}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BaseName,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </sdk:TreeView>`
```

Folders1 = the navigationProperty

would this need little trick work with mvvm ?
if so: how ?

i tried : {Binding Folders.folders1} where Folders is a working property from ModelView
but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to employ IValueConverter, take a look at this post:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/217562/517826.aspx